# Bootstrap Button Dropdown hidden behind div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just can not find any solution to my Problem.
My .dropdown menu is hidden behind my .media div.
I tried everything from position:relative/absolute to z-index, but i does not work in either of those cases.
Maybe you can help me out.
Thank you very much!

```
<div class="btn-group "  >
  <button type="text" class="btn " style="background-color: #22CAFF">Sortieren nach</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn  dropdown-toggle" style="background-color: #22CAFF" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="caret"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu "  style="position: fixed; z-index: 10000;">
    <?php echo get_options();    ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class='media' id='Erg_Praxis' style='overflow:visible;'>
   <div class='media-left media-middle'>
     <a href='SuchePraxis.php?id=$Id'>
      <img class='media-object' src='../upload/$Bild'  alt='Bild $Praxisname'> </a>
   </div>
   <div class='media-body'>
     <h4 class='media-heading'> </h4>                                                                               
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you put the jsfiddle in your question, it's too many possibility to get it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since your dropdown is not working with the provided code I added a generic one and commented yours, as you can see the dropdown displays above the image:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="text" class="btn" style="background-color: #22CAFF">Sortieren nach</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" style="background-color: #22CAFF;" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="position: fixed; z-index: 10000;">
    <?php echo get_options();    ?>
  </ul>
</div> -->
<div class='media' id='Erg_Praxis' style='overflow:visible;'>
  <div class='media-left media-middle'>
    <a href='SuchePraxis.php?id=$Id'>
      <img class='media-object' src='../upload/$Bild'  alt='Bild $Praxisname'></a>
  </div>
  <div class='media-body'>
    <h4 class='media-heading'> </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```